# Sequence of epimorphisms of residually finite groups stabilizes

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, geometric-group-theory, linear-groups

Let $G_1 \to G_2 \to \cdots$ be a sequence of epimorphisms of finitely generated residually finite groups. Does it eventually stabilize? That is, are all but finitely many epimorphisms actually isomorphisms?

Note that finitely generated residually finite groups are Hopfian, so this excludes the simple counterexample of each $G_i$ being a fixed group and each epimorphisms being a fixed one onto itself.

The analogous result holds when the groups are residually free: this is Proposition 6.8 in Charpentier Guirardel ["Limit groups as limits of free groups"](https://eclass.uoa.gr/modules/document/file.php/MATH154/%CE%88%CE%B3%CE%B3%CF%81%CE%B1%CF%86%CE%B1%20%CE%A0%CE%B1%CE%BB%CE%B1%CE%B9%CF%8E%CE%BD%20%CE%A3%CE%B5%CE%BC%CE%B9%CE%BD%CE%B1%CF%81%CE%AF%CF%89%CE%BD/Guirardel-Champetier.pdf). The proof only uses the fact that residually free groups are residually $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$, and it seems that it can be adapted to the case where each $G_i$ is residually $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ for a fixed $n$. It seems unlikely that this holds for general residaully finite groups: the [Jordan-Schur Theorem](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Jordan-Schur_theorem_on_abelian_normal_subgroups_of_small_index) implies that for a general finite group the minimal degree $n$ such that it embeds into $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ can be arbitrarily large.

Is there another way to adapt the proof? Is there a counterexample?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is "no". The lamplighter group (which is infinitely presented) is a limit of a sequence of virtually free groups and surjective homomorphisms (see, for example, this [question and answers there](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/75784/is-there-a-non-hopfian-lacunary-hyperbolic-group)). All virtually free groups are residually finite.

Comment: Ah, OK! The limit here is actually a colimit in category theoretic terminology?

Comment: It is the inductive limit in the standard terminology.

Comment: Do you have a reference? I saw it mentioned in one of the comments of the question you cite but it does not say where it comes from

Comment: See the proof in the answer by YCor in the linked question. Of course it is not the original proof,

Comment: What I said [at that question](https://mathoverflow.net/a/75791/14094) is that every (infinite locally finite)-by-finite finitely generated group is an inductive limit of a sequence of non-injective epimorphisms of virtually free finitely generated groups. It's a straightforward consequence of the 1978 Bieri–Strebel paper. However, I believe it was never said explicitly before a few years ago.

Comment: The proof uses only the fact that an HNN extension of a finite group is virtually free. That was known long ago (the 60s?). The argument about lamplighter groups appeared in print in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.2072.pdf, a year later than the question in MO.I am not sure there were papers containing that result before 2012.

Answer (score 7):

In the same vein as dodd's answer, a counterexample can also be deduced from the second Houghton group $H_2$, which is defined as the group of bijections $L^{(0)} \to L^{(0)}$ that preserves adjacency and non-adjacency for all but finitely pairs of vertices in the bi-infinite line $L$. A presentation of $H_2$ is
$$\left\langle \sigma_i (i \in \mathbb{Z}), t \left| \array{ \sigma_i^2=1, \ i \in \mathbb{Z} \\ [\sigma_i,\sigma_j]=1, \ |i-j| \geq 2}, \ \array{\sigma_i\sigma_{i+1}\sigma_i= \sigma_{i+1}\sigma_i \sigma_{i+1} = 1, \ i \in \mathbb{Z} \\ t\sigma_it^{-1}= \sigma_{i+1}, \ i \in \mathbb{Z}} \right. \right\rangle$$
where $t$ corresponds to a unit translation and $\sigma_i$ to the permutation $(i,i+1)$. Now, truncate the presentation and define $G_n$ via
$$\left\langle \sigma_i (i \in \mathbb{Z}), t \left| \array{ \sigma_i^2=1, \ i \in \mathbb{Z} \\ [\sigma_i,\sigma_j]=1, \ n \geq |i-j| \geq 2}, \ \array{\sigma_i\sigma_{i+1}\sigma_i= \sigma_{i+1}\sigma_i \sigma_{i+1} = 1, \ i \in \mathbb{Z} \\ t\sigma_it^{-1}= \sigma_{i+1}, \ i \in \mathbb{Z}} \right. \right\rangle.$$
By using the relations $t\sigma_it^{-1}=\sigma_{i+1}$ in order to remove the generators $\sigma_0,\sigma_{-1},\ldots$ and $\sigma_{n+2},\sigma_{n+3},\ldots$, we find the following presentation of $G_n$:
$$\left\langle \sigma_1, \ldots, \sigma_{n+1}, t \left| \array{ \sigma_i^2=1, \ 1 \leq i \leq n+1 \\ [\sigma_i,\sigma_j]=1, \ |i-j| \geq 2}, \ \array{\sigma_i\sigma_{i+1}\sigma_i= \sigma_{i+1}\sigma_i \sigma_{i+1} = 1, \ 1 \leq i \leq n \\ t\sigma_it^{-1}= \sigma_{i+1}, \ 1 \leq i \leq n} \right. \right\rangle.$$
Observe from this presentation that $G_n$ decomposes as an HNN extension of
$$\left\langle \sigma_1,\ldots, \sigma_{n+1} \left| \array{ \sigma_i^2=1, \ 1 \leq i \leq n+1 \\ [\sigma_i,\sigma_j]=1, \ |i-j| \geq 2}, \ \sigma_i\sigma_{i+1}\sigma_i= \sigma_{i+1}\sigma_i \sigma_{i+1} = 1, \ 1 \leq i \leq n \right. \right\rangle,$$
which turns out to be isomorphic to the symmetric group $\mathfrak{S}_{n+2}$, where the stable letter conjugates $\langle \sigma_1,\ldots, \sigma_n \rangle$ to $\langle \sigma_2, \ldots, \sigma_{n+1} \rangle$. Thus, as the HNN extension of a finite group, $G_n$ must be virtually free.

The conclusion is that the canonical quotient maps $G_1 \twoheadrightarrow G_2 \twoheadrightarrow \cdots$ defines a sequence of epimorphisms between virtually free groups that does not stabilise.

**Remark:** By reproducing the above argument almost word for word with the lamplighter group $\mathbb{Z}_2 \wr \mathbb{Z}$ instead of the Houghton group $H_2$ provides the same conclusion. The reason is that these groups have a similar structure: they are of the form $C \rtimes \mathbb{Z}$ for some locally finite Coxeter group $C$ where $\mathbb{Z}$ acts on $C$ via an isometry of the graph defining $C$. (Loosely speaking, all the other groups of this form can be recovered from $\mathbb{Z}_2 \wr \mathbb{Z}$ and $H_2$, so there is no other interesting examples in this direction.)

Comment: Just as a remark, the "second Houghton group" $H_2$ was discovered much before Houghton (as it's consider by B.H. Neumann in the 30's). The third Houghton group is a quite nontrivial analogue of $H_2$, and, quite surprisingly then, is finitely presented. Another remark is that this example is covered by my remark to dodd's post (it's an (infinite locally finite)-by-cyclic finitely generated group, so it's no surprise it's the same argument since it's the same in this generality, which is much broader than only locally finite Coxeter with action on the Coxeter graph).

Comment: As a further remark, $H_2$ is isomorphic to $\textrm{Sym}_{\textrm{fin}}(\mathbb{Z}) \rtimes \mathbb{Z}$ where $\textrm{Sym}_{\textrm{fin}}(X)$ are the finitely supported permutations on the set $X$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ acts on $X = \mathbb{Z}$ by translation (the "infinite cyclic permutation"). And another interesting property: the Houghton groups $H_n$ have the property $FP_{n-1}$ but not $FP_n$.

Comment: @Ycor Perhaps a separate (or stupid) question: Assume $G$ is finitely generated and $1 \to L \to G \to \mathbb{Z} \to 1$ where $L$ is infinite locally finite. Are there such $G$ which are not isomorphic to a subgroup of $H_2$? Perhaps need to require that $G$ is solvable and/or residually finite for a positive answer?

Comment: I would say that $\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ (and so $\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus(\mathbb{Z}_2\wr\mathbb{Z})$ if you really want an (infinite locally finite)-by-$\mathbb{Z}$ group) does not embed in $H_2$.

Comment: @AGenevois the element of order 2 $(2n\leftrightarrow 2n+1)_{n\in\mathbf{Z}}$ and $n\mapsto n+2$ commute.

Comment: @ARG the answer is yes by a counting argument: there are $2^{\aleph_0}$ such groups but only countably many embed into $H_2$ (still it's not hard to produce examples).

Comment: @YCor, I am not sure to understand your example: your element of order two is not a finitely supported permutation, right? So how do you embed $\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ in $H_2$?

Comment: @AGenevois Thanks! Actually I was more wondering if there is a quasi-isometric embedding of such a $G$ (and yes, with $L$ infinite) in $H_2$. But since q.i. are too messy I reduced to subgroup, which is (as you point out) now too obvious. But I guess the question that such a $G$ does not virtually embed in $H_2$ can still be tackled by the counting argument Ycor pointed out.

Comment: @Ycor If you have already have one in mind, I'd be grateful for a (solvable residually finite) such $G$ which virtually does not embed in $H_2$.

Comment: @AGenevois sorry I'm stupid. But still, an embedding is given by the transposition $(0,1)$ on the one hand, and the shift $\dots \mapsto -3\mapsto -2\mapsto -1\mapsto 2\mapsto 3\mapsto 4\mapsto\dots$, fixing $0$ and $1$.

Comment: You're right. Now I feel stupid...

Comment: What about iterated wreath products? Does $\mathbb{Z}_2 \wr (\mathbb{Z}_2 \wr \mathbb{Z})$ virtually embeds into $H_2$?

Comment: @AGenevois I think this is correct, The $\ell^2$-isopermetric profile of Houghton's group has been computed by [Saloff-Coste & Zheng](https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.12872v1)  (that of $\mathbb{Z}_2 \wr (\mathbb{Z}_2 \wr \mathbb{Z})$ is also known from Pittet & Saloff-Coste). But by [Delabie,Koivisto,Le Maitre & Tessera](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.00719) this profile is monotonous under coarse embeddings. Hence there can be no coarse embedding of iterated lamplighter in $H_2$.

Comment: Interesting. I think the same conclusion can be obtained by a careful analysis of asymptotic cones. I know that the asymptotic cones of $\mathbb{Z}_2 \wr (\mathbb{Z}_2 \wr \mathbb{Z})$ have infinite topological dimension, and I guess that the asymptotic cones of $H_2$ are one-dimensional (by analogy with $\mathbb{Z}_2 \wr \mathbb{Z}$). However, I don't how to prove the latter assertion.

Comment: [at]AGenevois oh, that's also a nice idea! but I'm also not sure how to deal with it. What is clear is that all these groups have asymptotic dimension 1, since there is a Hurewicz-type formula for asymptotic dimension [in Dranishnikov&Smith, Asymptotic Dimension of Discrete Groups]: when $1 \to N \to G \to Q \to 1$ then $asdim(G) \leq asdim(N) + asdim(Q)$. Since here $N$ is locally finite, it has $asdim =0$ (and obviously here $asdim(Q) = 1$. So $asdim(G)=1$ (the lower bound follows from containing $\mathbb{Z}$). But probably looking at the asymptotic cone would reveal finer distinctions.

Comment: AGenevois: just a side[-meta-]note [in case you did not know already]: if you do not use @Ycor, Ycor will not be notified that you answered to him. The person who wrote the post [you in this case] is always notified of the comments, but you have to put an "arobase" before the name of any other user in order to notify an answer.

Comment: @AGenevois But the asymptotic cone behaves badly under coarse embeddings, including group embeddings (well, between f.g. groups they induce Lipschitz maps, but which can be non-injective or non-proper). So asymptotics cones will not be of much use. (Still, the question about dim of asymptotic cone of $H_2$, is intriguing, independently; this could be asked separately.)

Comment: @YCor: Right, but I have a finer argument in mind. I would like to use a specific configuration in $\mathbb{Z}_2 \wr (\mathbb{Z}_2 \wr \mathbb{Z})$ implying the infinite dimension of asymptotic cones and to "rescale" its image in $H_2$ under a coarse embedding in order to deduce that the asymptotic cones of $H_2$ should also be infinite-dimensional. However, I didn't write all the details, so there is no guarantee it actually works...

Comment: Anyway the idea that the asymptotic cones of $H_2$ are 1-dimensional sound speculative. For instance, I checked long ago that the asymptotic cones of $C_2\wr Z^2$ are $\infty$-dimensional (and not 2-dimensional as a naive analogy with $C_2\wr Z$ would predict).

Comment: @YCor: I know, but the point that $\mathbb{Z}_2 \wr H$ has finite dimensional asymptotic cones iff $H$ has linear growth shows that there is something specific with the line, and $H_2$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2 \wr \mathbb{Z}$ are similar in many ways. For instance, $H_2$ has also a "lamplighter interpretation" (i.e. an arrow moving and acting on a colored line). But I agree that this is speculative, and I don't have any strategy to attack the problem right now.

Comment: One big difference between $C_2\wr Z$ and $H_2$ is that in $H_2$ I expect there are permutations supported by $\{-n,\dots,n\}$ that have size $\gg n$ (quadratic or even cubic, I'm not sure). Say, the permutation $m\mapsto -m$ of $\{-n,\dots,n\}$. This is rather analogous to $C_2\wr Z^2$, where there are configurations of quadratic size that are "supported" in the $n$-ball (that is, turning on all lights in the $n$-ball).

Comment: @Ycor & AGenevois: in a different direction, it could be also sufficient to compare the compression of these groups. But I don't know if the compression of either groups ( $C_2 \wr (C_2 \wr \mathbb{Z})$ or $H_2$) is known. The lower bounds I can gather are definitively not enough: $\alpha\big(C_2 \wr (C_2 \wr \mathbb{Z}) \big) \geq 4/7$ and $\alpha(H_2) \geq 1/2$.

Comment: @ARG: I have to check the details, but $H_2$ seem to act on a finite-dimensional CAT(0) cube complex with quasi-isometrically embedded orbits, so its (equivariant) Hilbert space compression should be 1.

Comment: @AGenevois ah yes.. that would be a good way to go at it. Actually I messed up: $C_2 \wr (C_2 \wr \mathbb{Z})$ is not Liouville, so its speed is linear and $\alpha \leq 1/2$. So as long as $H_2$ as a higher exponent (which seems very likely), this is a third possibility to exclude embeddings in $H_2$.